# given code of function f, how to decide statically if x effects f(x)?

Tags: static-analysis

If I have code for some function `f` (that takes in one input for simplicity), I need to decide if the input `x` affects the output `f(x)`, i.e, if `f` is a constant function defined below.

Define `f` to be constant function if output of `f` is invariant w.r.t `x`. This should hold for ALL inputs. So for example, if we have `f(x) = 0 power x`, it may output 0 for all inputs except for x = 0, where it may output error. So `f` is not a constant function.

I can only do static analysis of the code and assume the code is Java source for simplicity. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Well, except `0 ^ x` in Java is just `0 xor x`, which is always `x`.

Comment: Sorry I made typo.. I meant power. I corrected the post.

Comment: What should it output if `f` does not terminate?

Comment: Is `if(x==1) for(;;); else return 0;` a constant function, by your definition?

Comment: @nneonneo - great minds think alike :-)

Comment: @nneonneo I would call that non constant. I actually want to check if there is a `data dependency` from input to output.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously at least as hard as solving the Halting Problem (proof left as an exercise), so the answer is "no", this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certainly possible.  In most cases.  Where there aren't weird thing going on.

For normal functions, the ordinary, useful kind that actually return values rather than doing their own little thing, yes.

For a simple function, not recursive, no nastiness of that sort, doing it manually, I would probably make the static-analysis equivalent of a sign chart, where I examine the code and determine every value of x that might *possibly* be a boundary condition or such (e.g. the code has `if (x < 0)` somewhere in it, so I check the function for values of x near 0).  If this sort of attempt is doomed to fail please tell me before I try to use it on something.

Using brute force to grind away at it could work, unless you are working with quadruple precision x values or something similarly-sized, because then brute force could take years.  Although at that point its not really static-analysis anymore.

Static-analysis generally really means having a computer tell you by looking at the code, not you looking at it yourself (at least not very much).  Algorithms exist for doing this in many languages, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) has such a list, including some free or even open source.
The ultimate proof that something can be done is for it to have been done already.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'd call a non-terminating function non-constant, here's the reduction from your problem to the halting problem:

```
void does_it_halt(...);

int f(int x) {
    if(x == 1) {
        does_it_halt();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Asking if `f` is constant is equivalent to asking if `does_it_halt` halts. Therefore, what you're asking for is impossible, since the halting problem is undecidable.

Comment: we can say "possibly constant" ..(analysis time extended by a parameter)

Comment: Right. This is a completely solvable problem if you permit "maybe" answers -- the question is just how many "maybe" answers you are willing to accept. The trivial implementation, for instance, returns `maybe` for all inputs.